# Does this sentence example of perpetual lamentations make sense?

Tags: meaning

> The foreigners mourned with **perpetual lamentations for 3 months** following Murray's death.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers seem to focus on the *literal* meaning of "perpetual". But the Oxford dictionary gives this secondary definition:

> Occurring repeatedly; so frequent *as to seem endless* and uninterrupted.

I would say then that your sentence is quite acceptable. As a native British English speaker I can confirm that "perpetual" is used in a looser, hyperbolic way to mean either *frequent* or *persistent*, for example:

> Stop your perpetual whining

A "perpetual whiner" is quite a common insult (Google it!) and obviously does not mean that someone complains 24 hours a day every day without letup. It just means that they frequently complain.

Likewise, your sentence does not literally mean that their lamenting is expected to go on forever, just that it is so frequent and persistent so as to seem that way.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make sense, as perpetual means "without end, forever" and 3 months is a limited time frame.  Perpetual is a stronger word than even "endless", which is a word that would work in this sentence.  "Endless lamentations for 3 months..." would imply that they didn't stop their lamentations during these 3 months, but did stop after the 3 months.  Perpetual is a word that is exclusively used for things that NEVER end.

Comment: *Endless* wouldn't work either. It, too, means *without end*. It's no different than *perpetual*. The only words that work here are *continuous* and *continual*, depending on if there were interruptions or not. Assuming you want to interpret *endless* and *perpetual* in a literal sense. If you don't interpret *endless* literally, you don't need to interpret *perpetual* literally either.

Comment: *Endless* literally means without end, but colloquially can be used in a more limited manner.  It's implied that it's endless within a certain limit.  Perpetual, on the other hand, is typically used in a manner that expressly disallows setting boundaries around it.  Think about "Perpetuities" in contracts, which are clauses that are contractually required to be included in FUTURE contracts as well, making them never end even when you'd think it would end.

Comment: *Perpetual* can also be used colloquially. Perpetual motion machines and perpetual flames are not *really* perpetual. And contracts are frequently broken. Just like many marriages seldom actually end in parting in death.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed by my namesake, Richard, **perpetual** is not the right word to be used in your phrase.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**perpetual**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perpetual)

> continuing **forever**, or happening **all the time**

[**forever**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forever)

> for **all** time

For all time, during an **unlimited** time, not just for 3 months. Maybe the word that you are looking for is **uninterruptedly**

[**uninterruptedly**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uninterruptedly)

> in a way that is **without any pauses or interruptions**

The foreigners mourned **uninterruptedly** for 3 months following Murray's death